Equivalence of the stable set of A
Let be A hyperbolic matrix $R^{n\times n}$ Proof
$$x\in E^s(A) \leftrightarrow \exists K\geq 0: |\varphi_A(t,x)|\leq K, \forall t\geq 0$$
where $E^s(A)=\{x\in R^n; \lim_{+\infty}\varphi_A(t,x)=0 \}$
My attemp:Let be x in $E^s(A)$ then exists $k_0>0$ such that If $t>t_0 \rightarrow |\varphi_A(t,x)|<1$ And for $t \in [0,t_0]$ compact set, phi is continuos so it reaches its maximum, let's call him m. For K=max{1,m} the proposition is fulfilled.
For the converse. I have an idea all vector in $R^n$ can be written as the sum of vectores of stable set and the unstable set.
$$ x=v_1+v_2 ,v_1\in E^s(A), v_2\in E^u(A)$$
Now if I restrict the matrix to its unstable set then the matrix is ​​topologically conjugate to I, since all its eigenvalues ​​have a negative real part. For theorem there are constants $\mu>0$ and $k\geq 1$ such that:
$$|\phi_M(t,v_2)|\geq K^{-1}e^{\mu t}|v_2|$$
where M is the restricted matrix. then varphi tends to infinity if $v_2$ is different from 0.
But varphi is bounded so $v_2=0$. The problem is that the theorem I applied to M and not directly to A.I think This argument needs to be formalized.
